# VB.NET block .exe to launch

Tags: vb.net, locking, exe, blocking

does someone have an example code for how to prevent .exe files to be started?

Something like this might work:

```
For Each OSKInstance As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("OSK").ToArray
OSKInstance.Kill()
Next
```

But that might be resource intense as a while loop is running all the time. Is there a smarter way to lock an .exe?

Comment: Sure, just open the .exe file with FileStream using FileShare.None so Windows cannot open the file.  These kind of practices are self-defeating.  If the user wants the On Screen Keyboard then the user will get it.  By terminating your program.  Lock down kiosk style apps with a group policy.

Comment: what do you mean by kiosk style apps and can you be more specific regarding the group policies? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the code:

```
Dim myFileStream As System.IO.FileStream
Dim sFileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\test.exe"
'block
myFileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,    FileShare.None)
'unblock
myFileStream.Close()
```